# Unity Firebase remove listener for cloud function

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have trouble figuring out how to remove listener for cloud function which is triggered every few minutes. I have the following code:

```
void InitializeFirebase() {
      FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference ("Main").ValueChanged += ListenForServerTimestamp;
    }

void OnDisable() {
      FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Main").ValueChanged -= ListenForServerTimestamp;
    }
```

The issue is that the even is still registered even when Unity is not running. Ie play button is turned off, it is still registering the events. I must be doing something wrong with removing the events, but after looking through all other answers, i cant figure out what is the issue.

Thanks.

Edit: If there is some way to disconnect Firebase in Unity, that would be also something i could try. But i cant again find anything anywhere on disconnecting Firebase in Unity.

Comment: At first glance the way you remove the listener looks correct. Are you sure your `OnDisable` method is getting called? As an alternative you can also set `ValueChanged` to `null`, but I think it'd do the same here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I checked if OnDisable gets called with logs and it does get called when turning off Unity in editor. It probably does not relate to Cloud functions, but it was only thing i was thinking could be causing an issue, since i was not able to figure out whats wrong. I am just updating value in DB with Cloud function and listening to it with event in Unity. I am doing for now FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GoOffline() in Disable. I am not sure if thats good way to do it, if it wont mess up other things like anonymous auth etc. So would prefer regular way of removing listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My top suggestion will be to cache your database reference in the script where you're retrieving it. Something like this:

```
DatabaseReference _mainRef;

void InitializeFirebase() {
    _mainRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference ("Main");
    _mainRef.ValueChanged += ListenForServerTimestamp;
}

void OnDisable() {
    if(_mainRef != null) {
        _mainRef.ValueChanged -= ListenForServerTimestamp;
        _mainRef = null;
    }
}
```

If you inspect `GetReference`, you'll see something like this in ILSpy:

```
    public DatabaseReference GetReference(string path)
    {
      return new DatabaseReference(this.internalDatabase.GetReference(path), this);
    }
```

So you may be removing the listener on an object *other* than the one you register it on.

A few other things to double check. I'd recommend you do this on a `MonoBehaviour` rather than a `ScriptableObject`. Since you mention events getting triggered when the play button isn't selected, I expect that this is happening in Editor. `ScriptableObject` generally doesn't behave the way I'd expect in Editor and can cause odd issues around play/pause.

If it is on a `MonoBehaviour`, I would recommend that you not place it on one that has the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` attribute. You can also get odd behavior if you're invoking some of these calls from an Editor script (CustomEditor, PropertyDrawer, &c).

I don't think any of these (other than the ref) are your issue. But it's a few more things to look at.

I hope this helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks a lot for the info. I have tried to set the reference as you suggested, but it unfortunately did not help. I am running the code on monobehaviour and there is nothing special about it, so i am a bit clueless why its not working. I have made reproducible example here on Github https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/582 if you would be interested to have a closer look. Do you suggest some other way to listen to db if this is not working? Thanks. Luke

Comment: Edit: I double checked and i didnt implement your suggestion correctly. Now its working. Perfect. Thanks a lot Patrick, could not figure this out in days and i have gone through everything i could find.

Comment: Sorry to bother again Patrick, one more related question :) Its all working now except for one scenario. 
 When i setup listeners in Scene1, then go to Scene2 and update the DB with some value and go back to Scene1, now it fires the listener function twice. Only at this scenario. If i update the DB now again, back in Scene1 ( without turning off the editor ), it gets called only once. So it seems the listener is attached only once, yet before it was called twice. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Off of the top of my head, it may be:
1) (probably most likely) you're not unregistering listeners in your `OnDestroy` (or however else you'd like to manage scene transitions/Unity lifecycle events). Since these are native C# events, they don't respect Unity specific lifecycle oddities as a `UnityEvent` would.
2) You could be hitting the cache then getting a server sync. See if your data is identical both times.
3) it may be a bug in some corner case and you could file an issue or reach out to support to track.

Comment: Hi Patrick, you are a Pro. The main thing where we do mistakes we do not use exactly the same reference to register and unregister the events. getting a new reference for the same object from Firebase and removing an event from that does not work, but using a single reference does that perfectly. Thanks!!!